# Why Isn't My TableView Updating?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am using this code to save string as property "name" of entity "Exercise".  I notice that after method is called, the new cell does not appear.  Rather, I have to go up one level in the table, then go back to this table, then I see the new cell there.  Any ideas why this is happening?

I took out the viewDidLoad call.
**Updated code (without calling viewDidLoad)**

```
@implementation RoutineDayTableViewController
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

- (void)dealloc
{
    [selecctedExercise release];
    [managedObjectContext release];
    //[__fetchedResultsController release];
    [exerciseChooserView release];
    [cancelButton release];
    [tableView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(exerciseChooser)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];

    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  managedObjectContext);


    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if(editing){
        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    } else {
        // delete section
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.exerciseChooserView = nil;
    self.cancelButton = nil;
    self.tableView = nil;
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Exercise Editing

-(IBAction)exerciseChooser
{
    RoutineExerciseChooserViewController *routineExerciseChooserViewController = [[[RoutineExerciseChooserViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:routineExerciseChooserViewController animated:YES];
}

-(void)addExercise
{   /* 
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(exerciseChooser)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];

    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }

    Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    exercise.name = selectedExercise;

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    NSInteger lastSection = [self.tableView numberOfSections] -1;

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection]-1 inSection:lastSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

    [tableView reloadData];
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];
     */
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }

    Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    exercise.name = selectedExercise;

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    NSInteger lastSection = [self.tableView numberOfSections] -1;

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection]-1 inSection:lastSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

}

- (IBAction)dismssexerciseChooser
{
    [exerciseChooserView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(exerciseChooser)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];
    self.navigationItem.title = self.title;  
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [exerciseChooserView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){ [exerciseChooserView removeFromSuperview]; }];
}


-(void)toggleEdit
{
    [self.tableView setEditing: !self.tableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.tableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Cancel"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    Exercise *tempExercise = (Exercise *)[__fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = tempExercise.name;

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        // Delete the managed object for the given index path
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        NSLog(@"fetched results : \n%@\n",[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]);

        // Commit the change.
        NSError *error = nil;

        // Update the array and table view.
        if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
        {
            // Handle the error.
        }
        //[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
    }
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"name"] description];
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

     DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}    

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller delegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type)
    {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

/*
 // Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed. 

 - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
 {
 // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
 [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
 */


@end


-(void)addExercise
{    
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(exerciseChooser)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];

    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];

    Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    exercise.name = selecctedExercise;

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    NSInteger lastSection = [self.tableView numberOfSections] -1;

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection]-1 inSection:lastSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

Original Code

```
-(void)addExercise
{    
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];

    Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    exercise.name = selecctedExercise;

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    NSInteger lastSection = [self.tableView numberOfSections] -1;
    [self viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection]-1 inSection:lastSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Just a question: why are you calling the viewDidLoad method ?

Comment: If you execute [managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];
before the save operation, does the situation change? Hm, unlikely.

Comment: Thanks, HeikoG, I am calling the viewDidLoad because the last view was animated out and I need to set the nav bar title and init the buttons in the navbar which is all done in viewDidLoad.

Comment: you should never call `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:` or any other of the methods that get called by the framework manually. Especially not if the `viewDidLoad` method calls `[super viewDidLoad]`.

Comment: Ok, i fixed that, but the table still doesn't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you wired up your `UITableViewDataSource` delegate methods correctly?

For starters, make sure `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` returns at least `1`, `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns the correct number of exercises, and `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns a cell.

Comment: Yes everything is wired up correctly, remember when I go back up one hierarchy table, and back to this table, the cell is there, it just doesn't show unless I go up and back down the hierarchy of tables.  So like the table isn't updating right when the cell should be added or something.  I think it has something to do with `viewDidLoad` not loading because I am calling `addExercsie` from a different view.